# how to replace if elif in phyton to call functions?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing a chat bot, I need it to respond to certain commands in the chat, call certain functions. in addition to if else, nothing comes to mind, tell me how you can change the code in such a way as to remove or reduce the number of if else. The code is written as an example, there may be much more if

```
def func_text(text):
    return 'some text1...' + text

def func_summ():
    x = 5
    return x + x
    
def func_send_massege(text: str):
    return print(text)

def func_save(y):
    file = open('file.bin', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(y, file)
    file.close()

text = input()

if text == 'option1':
    func_send_massege(func_text(text))
elif text == 'option2':
    func_save(func_sum())
```

Comment: A dict that maps strings to functions.

Comment: if you use a dictionary, the problem arises that when initializing the dictionary, the functions inside the dictionary are executed immediately, and I need them to be executed only on command. It is impossible to write them inside the dictionary without (), because they must receive data from other functions

Comment: As the answers show: don't call the functions, just put them in a dict.

Answer (score 2):

```
text = ''
def func1():
    pass
def func2():
    pass
def func3():
    pass

def default():
    pass

actions = {'option1': func1, 'option2': func2, 'option3': func3}

try:
    actions[text]()
except KeyError:
    default()
```

Comment: `actions.get(text, default)()` ;)

Comment: @mozway I prefer `[]` syntax and explicit error over `.get`

Comment: I tried to do this, in this case, the functions from actions are executed immediately when the code is run, which leads to an error, because there are no variables yet

Comment: Are you sure you defined it as in the example I had given? Notice lack of `()` for the functions in the dictionary definition.

Comment: you're right! I have finalized the question code! in my case, a function is executed that should get a value from another function

Comment: @Basemen Could you expand your example a bit more? As it is, it isn't very clear where those variables come from, and your `func4`, `func5` and `func6` all do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @matszwecja expanded the example, for more understanding

Answer (score 2):

You should not use try and except to check if an item is in a dictionary. It is way better to use the `dictionary.get(key, fallback)` function. The code would look something like this:

```py
text = ''

def func1():
    #User typed "option1"
    pass

def func2():
    #User typed "option2"
    pass

def func3():
    #User typed "option3"
    pass

def default():
    #User typed something else
    pass


options = {
    'option1': func1,
    'option2': func2,
    'option3': func3
}

options.get(text, default)()
```

If you do not want to use a default function, you can just use:

```py
if text in options:
     options.get(text)()
```